# Can't convert string[] to byte[]

Tags: c#, directory, byte, converters

What i'm doing is this:

```
ArrayList files = new ArrayList();
byte[] tempFile;
string image;

foreach (string file in files)
{
    image = "/Images/Gallery/" + album.Substring(94) + "/" + file;

    tempFile = Directory.GetFiles(image);
}
```

I can't convert the string[] Directory.GetFiles(image) to byte[] tempFile. 
How can this be done?

Comment: Well, you're trying to convert a list of files - not the content - into a byte array. Is this *really* what you want to do?

Comment: `GetFiles` return an Array of strings ! you can't convert that to array of bytes. maybe an array of arrays of bytes ?

Comment: Use **`Path.Combine`** instead of building your path by hand. The directory separator char is platform-dependent.

Comment: @codesparkle Won't fix the issue, but is certainly a *suggestion* for hygiene, yes. =)

Comment: You do know that Direcotry.GetFiles returns an array of file names? not the content of the file?

Comment: I had an idea that GetFiles returned more than one file, what I want is to get a files bytes from a specified path

Answer (score 7, accepted):

please try this:

...

```
{
    image = Path.Combine("Images", "Gallery", album.Substring(94), file);
    tempFile = File.ReadAllBytes(image);
}
```